# Is this inconsistent treatment of `void` return from sql and plpgsql functions documented?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

```
begin;
create table foo(id integer);
create function f1() returns void language sql as $$delete from foo;$$;
create function f2() returns void language plpgsql as $$begin delete from foo; end;$$;
select f1() is null, pg_typeof(f1()), f1()::text, f1()::text is null;
/*
 ?column? | pg_typeof | f1 | ?column?
----------+-----------+----+----------
 t        | void      |    | t            <----------------------the return is null
*/
select f2() is null, pg_typeof(f2()), f2()::text, f2()::text='';
/*
 ?column? | pg_typeof | f2 | ?column?
----------+-----------+----+----------
 f        | void      |    | t            <----------------------the return is not null
*/
rollback;
```

Is this a documented inconsistency?

*SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eba82/4)*

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it's documented. The behavior is incorrect or at best inconsistent but maintained probably because of a huge existing user code base that would break if it were corrected. The issue is caused by differences in how returns VOID is coded with SQL vs plpgsql. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319986/postgresql-functions-returning-void

Comment: thanks for the tremendously useful link. Not sure I agree about the 'huge existing user code base that would break': I think it's unlikely much code will be relying on the return from a void-returning function.

Comment: @JackDouglas: Yeah, I still think this should be unified (or at least documented). Unifying the behavior might break some old code, but I, too, doubt that this has been used a lot. I never got around to report the bug. I probably should have ...